# How do I switch the Rails ORM to a purely SQL based queries?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, orm

My project is currently set up to use Rails the normal way with Active Records. However, my boss wants me to migrate the current project ORM to move into a more SQL-like ORM. He wants the database queries in the Rails project to be pure SQL code as He does not want to see database queries the Rails way with Active Record.
I have no idea of how to go about this. How do I make sure Rails is set to use only pure SQL queries everywhere in the code ?

Comment: What is a "more SQL-like ORM"? Every rails query to a SQL database is a pure SQL query. How could it be anything else? Why would your boss do this to you? Is it just because he/she can't understand it? Are they asking you to use core types like `Hash` and `Array` instead? BTW this is a horrible idea IMO and will make your application less maintainable and potentially more vulnerable. In addition if you already have this application running what you are actually proposing is a complete tear down and rebuild there is no, just swap it out.

Comment: One of the advantages of using rails is leveraging ActiveRecord, which 95% of the time does exactly what you need it to without a problem.  It is also flexible enough to let you use AREL or raw SQL when you absolutely NEED to. Writing your own crappy ORM to replace it is such a waste of time and such a security risk, it is malpractice.